# You do not have permission to access this content in HTML Profile Form

Tags: wordpress, webform-civicrm, profile, civicrm.settings.php, html

We have published a CiviCRM profile form at *https://www.redmaternoinfantil.org.mx/educacion/*, we place this form with the HTML code that CiviCRM provided me.

We want to receive the information external to our CiviCRM but when trying to send the form, it automatically redirects us to a permission denial link.

```
  https://www.redmaternoinfantil.org.mx/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fuf%2Fgroup
```

The message on the screen is

> You do not have permission to access this content

```
<div><input name="entryURL" type="hidden" value="https://www.redmaternoinfantil.org.mx/civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&amp;amp;q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fsetting%2Fpreferences%2Fdate&amp;amp;page=CiviCRM&amp;amp;action=update&amp;amp;id=7&amp;amp;reset=1" />
<input name="gid" type="hidden" value="15" />
<input name="contact_sub_type_hidden" type="hidden" value="Beneficiarias" />
<input name="_qf_default" type="hidden" value="Edit:next" />
</div>
```

Log:

> [debug] $backTrace = #0 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(441): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure the anonymous and authenticated users have 'CiviCRM: profile create' permission.

Comment: That's great advice but it hasn't fixed it.
This CiviCRM installation allows me to control user permissions in "WordPress Access Control" and by checking the "Create and Edit Profiles" boxes for anonymous users, but this didn't work. I have also verified the groups because I need the new records coming from the HTML forms of the profiles to be saved in a group and I have changed the permissions of this group from "Only users and administrator" to "Public pages" and it did not work either.  https://www.redmaternoinfantil.org.mx/educacion/

Answer (score 0):

In the profile settings, under the Advanced section at the bottom, what do you have for "Redirect URL"? You can put a url for a public page that says "Thanks" or something.

Comment: @Demérito I did that, but it only works with authenticated users and for external users it redirects to something else.